# How to develop lock mechanism based on operations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, locking

I have 3 different operations: `add`, `delete` and `get`.

While there can be any number of `get` operations running in parallel, there can't be any operations parallel to `add` and `delete` ie., while adding new items there can't be any `add`, `delete` or `get` operations. This holds for `delete` operations too.

If I just use a lock object, parallel get operations can't be done. What is the right way to implement this lock mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want a "Reader-Writer" lock. Python doesn't have it by default (I think). You may want to google search external libraries.

[This came up from a google search](https://pypi.org/project/readerwriterlock/). I haven't used it, but from the docs, usage seems quite straightforward.

Or if you want to roll out your own implementation, you could potentially do it with `threading.Condition` while keeping track of number of readers.